# How to save NSBezierPath shapes in a NSImageView into .PNG or JPEG format?

Tags: swift, macos

I am having a problem.

I am developing a kind of paint for mac os. In a Imageview, I draw shapes thanks to NSBezierPath object.

Now, I want to implement the saving functionality.

But I do not know how to do.

Anyone could help? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't see how you relate NSBezierPath to NSImageView.  Please show us your work.

Comment: The image view has a property `image` which is an `NSImage`. There are countless sites (and answers here on SO) which explain how you can save an `NSImage` as png or jpeg.

Comment: Thanks, but if I save this NSImage, will I save the NSBezierPath shapes aswell ?

Comment: Please first try and post what you have tried in case it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean? The shapes as NSBeszerPaths so that you can load and manipulate them? no.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answer, I solved my problem. I use the createPDFInRect which is the NSView's method !